# Which PDF API can i use to get a document with dynamic fields?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I have a problem to choose which PDF API can i use to generate a pdf with dynamic fields...
I've used jasper report some time ago but the requirements has changed and now i have dynamic fields...
It means that in one report i can have "Name, Phone, Address" and in another i can have "Name, Address, Age, Phone, Birthday"... I've no how to know which fields im gonna have in the report until the use choose the fields to be impressed...
If i try using jasper report and the use dont choose some field im gonna have a big space with blank content...

I were thinking if is there some how to make a loop into jasper...
I mean, i get a list of object and into those objects im gonna have another list...
SOmeone understood my problem or have some idea about how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a Velocity template that contains an FO representation of your PDF, populate the dynamic variables, and then turn it into a PDF using an FO Transformer.  No Jasper required.

Comment: can u tell me a little more about the velocity template? some link, o sample about it? thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at generating the PDF documents using IText:

http://itextpdf.com/

It's a relatively easy to use API, but will be programming heavy compared to something like Jasper.

Comment: yeah... i saw that API... and im thinking to use this one but im looking around to check if isn't there some better way... Thanks for helping!!